# How to sub a C++ class from a .so on Linux?

Tags: linux, loadlibrary, shared-libraries

I am using the ACE library to do some reactor jobs. On linux ,the default ACE compile output is the libACE.so. I usually to compilte it with the -lACE compile option, but this rely on whether i have configured the libACE.conf in ld.so.conf.d directory.
   If I want to sub class ACE_Task,which could be imported from ACE.so , the compile rely on the libACE.so, if I want to dynamic load the ACE.so , how can i do this?
   I have tried, if i use dlopen , then the link error occurs.
   so ,is there any way to load ACE.so dynamically and still can implement the ACE_Task like this?

```
class test: public ACE_Task<ACE_MT_SYNCH>
{

}
```

Comment: So do you have the library configured with `ld.so.conf`?

Comment: I have configured it with the ld.so.conf，this is fine with compile,but when i want to release all the files on another PC, i have to configure the ld.so.conf， Is there any way to sub-classing a class which is the from .so file and i can still load it at run time?

Answer (score 1):

Sub-classing happens mostly at compilation time. You need to have the super-class[es] appropriately defined in some header file[s].

At runtime, what matters is the availability of vtables and inherited member functions (and perhaps RTTI).

You probably want to link the `libACE.so` to your shared object (the `dlopen`-ed thing you are building). This is possible with eg `g++ -rdynamic -shared your*.pic.o -lACE -o yoursharedobject.so`